# Make scope and instance method with same conditions more DRY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

Say you have a model that defines a scope, the conditions of which are also used in an instance method:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :complete?, -> {
    where(
      foo: true,
      bar: true,
      baz: true
    )
  }

  def complete?
    foo? && bar? && baz?
  end
end
```

If you needed to change the definition of `complete?`, you would have to remember to change both the scope and the instance method. Is there a nice way to consolidate these two definitions and make the code a bit more DRY?

The problem gets slightly more complex if one of the conditions is itself an instance method:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :complete?, -> {
    where(
      foo: true,
      bar: true,

      # can't use instance method `base?` here for `baz` condition
      # you would have to duplicate the logic:
      name: 'baz'
    )
  }

  def baz?
    name == 'baz'
  end

  def complete?
    foo? && bar? && baz?
  end
end
```

Comment: Why there is a scope with "?"(scope :complete?)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DRY means "don't repeat yourself". In those snippets I don't see any duplication whatsoever. So there's literally nothing to DRY up.

What you probably meant, though, is

> there is one piece of information from which two methods are generated. If this information changes, how to be able to change it only once, so that I don't accidentally forget to update some other place?

Well, you can do some metaprogramming gymnastics such as this:

```
class Thing < ActiveRecord::Base
  FIELDS_FOR_COMPLETE = {
    foo: true,
    bar: true,
    baz: true,
  }

  scope :complete?, -> {
    where(FIELDS_FOR_COMPLETE)
  }

  def complete?
    FIELDS_FOR_COMPLETE.all? do |method_name, expected_value|
      self.public_send(method_name) == expected_value
    end
  end
end
```

It's up to you to decide which one is easier to read, to understand and to maintain.

Me, I choose the first (somewhat duplicated) version. It makes me think less. And it's also immediately obvious to any other rails programmer, which might join the project.

Comment: I take your point about there being no duplication. The scope and instance method serve separate purposes after all. I had experimented with some solutions like yours above, but my emphasis would be on readability in this case so will stick with the "duplication" as suggested